# Is it possible reduce power transmission of WiFi P2P(WiFi Direct)?

Tags: java, android, wifi, transmission

I'd like to know if there is a way, in android programming, to reduce Wifi Direct's range transmission. I'm only interested if there is a code that works without root. Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is operating system controlled (if at all, usually this is once set in kernel driver for your wifi chipset and never touched again). There is a power save mode in android which will set the chipset in a powersave mode, but what that means is wildly different for the chipset that is being suspended. Some are reducing power transmission, some are disabling all transmission. Howerver, you can't influence it from android code. (Not without root and extensive system changes along the way)

Comment: Are you sure of this? 'Couse in this article"http://www.thinktube.com/tech/android/wifi-direct" at the fifth point says it's possible becouse is a feature of wifi direct.

Comment: According to this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html and this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html it is not possible.